# How to add "Single" Multi-Roles Exchange Server 2016 to Exchange 2016 DAG - Two Nodes Servers (*Without HW load balancer)

Tags: exchange

How do I add existing 1 x "Physical" Microsoft Exchange 2016 multi-roles server to New 2 nodes Exchange 2016 DAG -Active Passive ? However, I do not have "Hardware Load Balancer"

In more detail

The existing environment has 1 x Microsoft Exchange 2016 Single Server with Multi-roles (*Physical Server) The operating System for the Exchange Server - Microsoft Windows 2016 std. Now I would like to change the existing environment from Single Server to form a "Microsoft Exchange 2016 DAG" 2 nodes servers. However, my concern is the existing "Single Exchange 2016 Server" is running in production and it is a physical machine, will it cause a lot of impact if Changing this Single Multi-Roles Exchange Server to new Exchange 2016 DAG (*Two Nodes) Active/ Passive. Finally, since the original design issue. Customer does not have additional budget for purchasing the additional "HW load balancer". Many thanks.

Comment: Dear All, The existing environment has follow:

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you are having one Exchange server in physics machine, and want to deploy a DAG (2 nodes)?

If yes, where do you want to create the secondary Exchange server, another physics machine, or on the current same server by virtual machine?

It is recommended to deploy the secondary server with another physics machine, check the [requirement for servers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/high-availability/plan-ha?view=exchserver-2019) and follow the steps with [DAG deployment](https://pdhewaju.com.np/2016/12/15/dag-configuration-on-exchange-2016/). If no HLB, try [DNS round robin](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1687be3d-b5c1-4026-98fe-63297f443879/exchange-2013-dag-using-round-robin-dns?forum=exchangesvravailabilityandisasterrecovery).

Answer (score 0):

Introducing a DAG means changing your exchange infrastructure.
That should be done with a plan. You can introduce a DAG gradually with almost no downtime but a having a test environment is recommended. And, infrastructure changes have to be performed in a planned maintenance window.
Some details here:
https://practical365.com/exchange-server/exchange-2016-database-availability-groups/

Having no load balancer means you are left with a crippled HA as DNS has no means to detect unresponsive servers. 
You could use a free OVA as LB: https://freeloadbalancer.com/
Find some details here about LB concepts.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/architecture/client-access/load-balancing?view=exchserver-2019